# How to output raw code in github's wiki?

Tags: github, wiki, markdown

I want to explain my wiki users how to use internal links. However, when I write `[[Linktext|Link to an internal site]]` with two `` (code dashes) around them, it gets displayed as a link, but preformatted as code.

How can I get it outputed as raw format, so that my wiki's users can see how to enter internal links?

Comment: If can escape the second bracket and get a raw output with [\ [\[Linktext|Link to an internal site]], but can't display it as code with two added ` that way...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do so, since some HTML is supported within GitHub's Markdown. Here is an implementation that I was successful in getting:

Assuming that you want to output `[[Link|Link]]`, you can add "`<code>&#91;[Link|Link]]</code>`" into the text editor. It makes sure that the output will be parsed properly and the link does not render.

Note: "`&#91;`" is the HTML code for "`[`".